# Chrome infobars infect other windows

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to figure out what seems to be the problem, so please be patient as I will update the question as it gets clearer to me what is happening.

I'm writing automated tests with Selenium and Java in IntelliJ 2019. Now, since upgrading Chrome to version 75.0.3770.142 (**but**, I'm not 100% sure if this was happening before) this is the observed behavior:

1. Open Chrome manually (nothing unusual is noticed)
2. Start the Selenium test from IntelliJ
3. Another Chrome window is opened (with the `Chrome is being controlled by automated test software` bar at the to
   p).
4. Switch to the window from step #1 and it too is showing the infobar

This is my method for initializing the Chrome driver:

```
public static void initChromeDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\path-to\\chromedriver.exe")
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

Has anyone else had this before?

Or, please suggest what would be other useful info to add.

Comment: This happens because you are forcing selenium to point to the default  chrome directory using `options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");`. Try commenting that line, if you are not specifically interested in launching the default profile. So that you don't see the info bar on the manually opened chrome instance.

Comment: @supputuri Yes, that was it. But why does it happen with the already opened window? That was strange. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: `options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are forcing selenium to point to the default chrome directory using `options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");`. Try commenting that line, if you are not specifically interested in launching the default profile. So that you don't see the info bar on the manually opened chrome instance.